# Group by distinct users - mental block

Tags: mysql

I'm having a mental block and I need some help working out how to build a report. What I'm trying to do is create a table showing how many of my customers only transact at a certain price point (which I've bucketed).

I've got a table of how many 'buckets' each user is in, but I can't work out how to the opposite of it.

What I'm effectively looking for is a table like:

```
Volume Band     | Users
A (0 - 1000)    | 5
B (1000 - 3000) | 3
C (3000 - 5000) | 1
etc
```

And, what I currently have is:

```
ID    | No of Bands
56    | 3
75    | 2
13    | 1
etc
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
select
    t1.id,
    count(distinct(t1.volume_band)) as no_of_bands
from
(
    select
        id,
        case 
            when charged between 0 and 1000 then "A (0-1,000)" 
            when charged between 1000 and 3000 then "B (1,000 - 3,000)"
            when charged between 3000 and 5000 then "C (3,000  5,000)"
            when charged between 5000 and 7000 then "D (5,000 - 7,000)"
            when charged between 7000 and 9000 then "E (7,000 - 9,000)"
            when charged between 9000 and 11000 then "F (9000 - 11,000)"
            when charged between 11000 and 13000 then "G (11,000 - 13,000)"
            when charged between 13000 and 15000 then "H (13,000 - 15,000)"
            when charged between 15000 and 17000 then 'I (15,000 - 17,000)'
            when charged between 17000 and 20000 then 'J (17,000 - 20,000)'
            when charged between 20000 and 25000 then 'K (20,000 - 25,000)'
            when charged between 25000 and 30000 then 'L (25,000 - 30,000)'
            else "M (30,000+)"
        end as volume_band,
        count(payment_id)
    from
        table
    where
        DATE_FORMAT(payment_date,'%Y-%m') >= '2018-04'
    and user_type = 'a'
    group by 1,2) as t1
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

I've tried something similar to the below but I get an error saying 't1.volume band' isn't in column list:

```
select
t1.volume_band,
count(distinct(t1.user_id)
...
where count(distinct(t1.volume_band)) = 1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Agree with the above.  While you did provide a minimal sample problem, it apparently has little connection to your actual tables.

Comment: Please don't add screenshots. Please remove the screenshots.

Comment: Then not sure what you want me to do. The example table above is an accurate example of what the table I'm using look like.

Comment: Getting down votes for this will just solve question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solving question as getting down-voted as I'm unable to provide clarity/MCVE that being asked for.

Apologies.